# Problems with php display folders in template

Tags: php, html, templates, foreach, undefined

everyone!
I want to display folder's name in the table in HTML template.

PHP:

```
$path = "albums/";
$albums = scandir($path);
$skip = array('.', '..')

;
```

HTML template:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Альбом</th>
        <th colspan="2">Операции</th>
    </tr>

    <? foreach ($albums as $album): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php print $album ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">
                Редактировать
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">
                Удалить
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <? endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, I get the error like this:

> Notice: Undefined variable: album in D:\xampp\htdocs\homework\5\view\albums.html on line 20

How can I display folders' name correctly? What was a mistake?

Comment: Do you have short tags enabled? That trailing semi-colon also is pretty strange.

Comment: Yes, I do. I changed the parameters in php.ini:  short_open_tag = On

Comment: Hmm if you view the source of the page is `<? foreach ($albums as $album): ?>` in there? It is not looping currently, right? Do you have `Редактировать` displayed multiple times or just once?

Comment: I want to display links "edit" and "delete" to each folder multiple times.

Comment: I get that, but it currently only displays one link for each, right? If you view the source those PHP tags are present?

Comment: You probably edited the wrong `php.ini` file. Look for one in the \xampp\apache\bin` folder that the one that controls PHP when running with Apache

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have short tags disabled. Try this.

```
<?php
$path = "albums/";
$albums = scandir($path);
$skip = array('.', '..');
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Альбом</th>
        <th colspan="2">Операции</th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach ($albums as $album): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php print $album ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">
                Редактировать
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">
                Удалить
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Comment: It didn't work. I think the mistake in loop. I got two mistakes "Notice: Undefined variable: albums in D:\xampp\htdocs\homework\5\view\albums.html on line 17

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\xampp\htdocs\homework\5\view\albums.html on line 17"  :D

Comment: @DariaShel i tested the code locally and it works just fine. Make sure you use the full path.

Comment: @DariaShel That error message reveals you a) didn't/don't have the short tags enabled AND b) you probably are including the other code bit with short tags which causes it to be undefined. All of this would be displayed in the source code.

Comment: @DariaShel chris is right. Since you had short tags mixed in this part of the code, i bet you have short tags in other parts as well. In your other comment you said you enabled short tags but still got the error. It seems like you actually haven't. Either enable short tags properly or make sure you replace all your short tags in the code.